# Значение словосочетания. Лосиные пробеди.

Tags: словарь

Думаю, это последнее, непонятное мне сочетание из упомянутого рассказа. Не нашёл значение в словарях, но полагаю, что имеется ввиду протоптаная лосями тропа. Как считаете?
P.S. контекста как такового нет. Просто упоминается при описании леса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задали Вы задачку!
Кое-что о повадках лосей :

> Рост {рогов} начинается весной, и летом рога еще покрыты бархатистой кожей. В июле-августе **лоси  чешут рога о стволы деревьев и бодают кусты**, очищая эту кожу. К этому времени каждый бык **выбирает себе место (точок), где он чистит рога**, роет копытами землю и ревет, призывая самку или производя на нее впечатление, если она уже пришла. А если появляется холостой соперник, пускает в ход рога.
> [Лоси](http://www.n-svirsky.ru/index.php?PART_CODE=RU&PAGE_CODE=ABT&page_id=10&z_page_id=30)

Из словаря Даля :

> **ПРОБОДАТЬ**, пробости или пробость и прободнуть что, пробить бодком, тычком, пропырять, пробутускать, проколоть, проткнуть, пронзить тычком. Корова быку бок прободнула. Мужику в драке вилами шею прободнули. Един из воин копием ребра ему прободе, Иоан. Воевода Блуд нача укоряти Болеслава, глаголя: прободем трескою (лучиной) твое чрево толстое! Никон. -ся, страд.
> | Коровы все утро прободались, между собою, взаимно. Прободенье ср. прободка жен. действие по гл. Прободитель, прободчик муж. -чица жен. прободавший что-либо.

Таким образом, "лосиные пробеди" (*прободи*?) могут оказаться местом, где лоси бодают деревья.